# Dialogflow sending null intents making app to crash

Tags: java, android, chatbot

I am making an android chatbot using `dialogflow`. I have initalized the webhook feature. The issue is the app keeps crashing

I am getting this error :

> 3-23 20:40:13.121 25844-25844/com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot I/com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot.MainActivity: Status type: partial_content
>   03-23 20:40:13.121 25844-25844/com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot I/com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot.MainActivity: Resolved query: hi
>   03-23 20:40:13.121 25844-25844/com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot I/com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot.MainActivity: Action: smalltalk.greetings.hello
>   03-23 20:40:13.122 25844-25844/com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot I/com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot.MainActivity: Speech: hey...........
>   03-23 20:40:13.122 25844-25844/com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot I/com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot.MainActivity: Intent id: null
>   03-23 20:40:13.122 25844-25844/com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot I/com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot.MainActivity: Intent name: null
>   03-23 20:40:13.122 25844-25844/com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot D/a: just recahde
>   03-23 20:40:13.122 25844-25844/com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   03-23 20:40:13.124 25844-25844/com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot, PID: 25844
>                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                    at com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:176)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6175)
>                                                                                    at com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot.MainActivity.onResult(MainActivity.java:138)
>                                                                                    at com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:39)
>                                                                                    at com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot.MainActivity$2.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:127)
>                                                                                    at com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot.MainActivity$2.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:104)
>                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
>                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>   03-23 20:40:13.124 25844-25844/com.khatkhatay.aqid.chatbot D/AppTracker: App Event: crash

MY CODE:

public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

```
ListView conversationList;
ImageButton sendButton;
EditText userInput;
AIConfiguration aiConfiguration;
AIDataService aiDataService;

public static ArrayList<ChatData> chatlist;
public static ChatAdapter chatAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages lang =
            AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.fromLanguageTag("en");

    aiConfiguration = new AIConfiguration("2f41a8be61ab4b70acf9b26e78ab8577",lang);
    aiDataService = new AIDataService(aiConfiguration);

    sendButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    userInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputMessage);

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String text = userInput.getText().toString();
            if(!text.trim().equals("")) {
                addMessage(text,true);
                userInput.setText("");
                sendRequest(text);
            }
        }
    });


    conversationList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ConversationList);
    conversationList.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
    conversationList.setStackFromBottom(true);

    chatlist = new ArrayList<ChatData>();
    chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(this, chatlist);
    conversationList.setAdapter(chatAdapter);


}

private void addMessage(String message, boolean isMine) {

    final ChatData chatMessage = new ChatData("", "","", isMine);
    chatMessage.body = message;
    chatAdapter.add(chatMessage);
    chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void sendRequest(String userText) {

    final String contextString = String.valueOf(userText);

    final AsyncTask<String, Void, AIResponse> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, AIResponse>() {

        private AIError aiError;

        @Override
        protected AIResponse doInBackground(final String... params) {
            final AIRequest request = new AIRequest();
            String query = params[0];

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(query))
                request.setQuery(query);

            try {
                return aiDataService.request(request);
            } catch (final AIServiceException e) {
                aiError = new AIError(e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final AIResponse response) {
            if (response != null) {
                onResult(response);
            } else {
                onError(aiError);
            }
        }
    };

    task.execute(contextString);
}

private void onResult(final AIResponse response) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResult");

            Log.i(TAG, "Received success response");

            // this is example how to get different parts of result object
            final Status status = response.getStatus();
            Log.i(TAG, "Status code: " + status.getCode());
            Log.i(TAG, "Status type: " + status.getErrorType());

            final Result result = response.getResult();
            Log.i(TAG, "Resolved query: " + result.getResolvedQuery());

            Log.i(TAG, "Action: " + result.getAction());

            final String speech = result.getFulfillment().getSpeech();
            Log.i(TAG, "Speech: " + speech);

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(speech))
                addMessage(speech,false);

            final Metadata metadata = result.getMetadata();
            if (metadata != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Intent id: " + metadata.getIntentId());
                Log.i(TAG, "Intent name: " + metadata.getIntentName());
            }

            final HashMap<String, JsonElement> params = result.getParameters();
            if (params != null && !params.isEmpty()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Parameters: ");
                for (final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, String.format("%s: %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString()));
                }
            }
            switch (metadata.getIntentName()){
                case "Weather":
                    getWeatherData(params);

                    break;
            }
        }

    });
}

private void parseData(JSONObject json){
    try {
        if(json.getJSONObject("query").getInt("count") > 0){

            String details = "";

            JSONObject channel = json.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("channel");

            details = "Weather looks " + channel.getJSONObject("item").getJSONObject("condition").getString("text") +
                    " in " + channel.getString("title").replace("Yahoo! Weather - ","");

            details = details + "\nTemprature is " + channel.getJSONObject("item").getJSONObject("condition").getString("temp")
                    + (char) 0x00B0 + "F.";


            addMessage(details,false);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void getWeatherData(HashMap<String, JsonElement> params) {

    String geoCity = "";
    if (params != null && !params.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Parameters: ");
        for (final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("%s: %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString()));
            if(entry.getKey().equals("geo-city"))
                geoCity = entry.getValue().getAsString();
        }
    }

    final AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>() {

        private AIError aiError;
        JSONObject weatherData = null;

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(final String... params) {
            final AIRequest request = new AIRequest();
            String query = params[0];

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22" + query + "%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"); //Enter URL here
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.connect();

                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String line;
                    String sb = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb = sb + line;
                    }

                    JSONObject myJsonArray = new JSONObject(sb);

                    //JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sb);

                    weatherData = myJsonArray;
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return weatherData;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final JSONObject response) {
            if (response != null) {
                parseData(response);
            } else {
            }
        }
    };

    task.execute(geoCity);
}

private void onError(final AIError error) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            addMessage(error.toString(),false);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: tried its not getting resolved

Comment: Ultimately its a NPE . Whats on `MainActivity.java:176`? can you point out

Comment: switch (metadata.getIntentName()){
                    case "weather":
                        getWeatherData(params);
                        break;
                }

Comment: Seems like `metadata.getIntentName()` is `null`. try to debug the code and find out the reason for null .

Comment: Is this  due to some logical error in the code or is the api sending a null intent?